# jQuery selector for divs with a dash on the class name?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to reference all img in an element. See my example below.

```
<div class="entry">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p><img src="something.jpg" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the above, I use `$(".entry > .entry-content > p > img")` but it doesn't seem to work. What is the correct way use the selector for class names that have dashes on them?

Comment: Your selector is ok. The problem must be somewhere else. Can you show us more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/yrTg3/

Your selectors are correct.  See your version working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yrTg3/1/

Not sure why you are doing that but this will work:

```
alert("see here ==> " + $("div.entry > div.entry-content > p > img").attr("src"));​
```

**Or**

Try passing attr 'class' in images and use `.each` function to iterate through.

Comment: why is everyone using such complicated selectors? when he just wanted all the images ?

Comment: Hiya @mkprogramming I reckon we are working on top of his/her solution. o yeah d'uh :) there are much easier ways innit! like the `.each` and loop through all the images by just passing `class` in all the `img` tags!

Comment: @mkprogramming All images in a specific element. Who knows how complex the selector should be. Maybe there are images directly in .entry-content that shouldn't be selected.

Comment: @mkprogramming: because this was not the question, his question is about dashes in selectors

Comment: sure, I can see that maybe some wouldn't be selected. He just said he wanted "all the images inside an element". It's a bummer people down voted my answer..

Comment: Whoah, I don't get it, it seemed to work after I applied Tats_innit's script then when I removed his script it still worked. Before I posted this question it never did work. Weird. Anyway, at least it got fixed. And thank you for getting my point @GolezTrol

Comment: @mkprogramming Maybe people downvoted your answer, because it wasn't very useful before you edited it, and you're nagging other people who did provide a helpful answer in the first place, just because you want some upvotes. Go answer an other question if you need the points so bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
$('.entry-content img')
```

You don't need to worry about the dash or anything.

You might want to change the last `</div?` to look like this: `</div>`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Corrected. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, but your last `</div>` is closed by a question mark instead of a `>`. Maybe that's the problem.